# Are there any Druid Circles which membership of would be irreconcilable with membership in the The Emerald Enclave?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, forgotten-realms, lost-mine-of-phandelver

I am a first-time DM and our entire group is relatively new to 5e, and none of us have played a druid before. I am running the Lost Mines of Phandelver module with my group. My party is about to reach 2nd level. One member of my party, Jal, is a Druid, at 2nd lvl they will have to pick their Druid Circle class feature. Jal's *Personal Goal* is to join [*The Emerald Enclave*](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Emerald_Enclave), and they are currently seeking out their role model [*Reidoth*](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Reidoth), an elusive member of the order.

We are sticking mostly to the 3 core rule books (which are also the only 3 we all have access to), PHB, DMG, & MM, however, I'd love to hear answers for content from any source material.

Are there any Druid Circles that would be difficult to reconcile with membership in the *Emerald Enclave*? Are there any Druid Circles whose members *Redioth* would be less inclined to deal with?

*Post-answer edit*: I realize now I could have added a bit of extra context to my question, but I think it's answered anyway. I know that druids can be a little funny socially, so I was mainly asking if there were any possible clique or negative association interactions possible that I could have missed with my cursory reading of the source books. It seems like there are not. It seems like the Druid Circles are socially similar to a Wizard's *School of Magic*, that is to say, it's merely a "this is how I do/focus on our profession" without any stigma or negative connotations typically (possible exception in the case of Wizards and Necromancy) being attached.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you *hoping* to find some circles that would make these things more difficult? Like, for dramatic purposes or something? Or are you hoping to *avoid* any circles that could make for these difficulties?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are discussing the subclass circles, and not in character circles?  Because one Moon druid of Malar can be very different from a Moon Druid of Melikki.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme, I'm trying to forsee (and if possible, avoid) any possible issues with the druid fulfilling their personal goal.

Comment: @Scrollreader, I am asking about the class feature that druids pickup upon reaching 2nd level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, you're good. Circle of the Land and Circle of the Moon both are perfectly acceptable to other druids, and druids wouldn't really be appalled by any of the other circles. Circle of Wildfire might make them nervous and Circle of Spores is kinda weird, but you should be fine.